# Field inside a cavity on round trip

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, cavity-qed

In the famous notes by [Daniel Steck](https://atomoptics-nas.uoregon.edu/%7Edsteck/teaching/quantum-optics/quantum-optics-notes.pdf), the electric field inside a resonator after one round trip is given by Eq. (12.1) as

$$E^{(+)} (t + \tau_{rt}) e^{-i \omega (t + \tau_{rt})} = r E^{+}(t) e^{-i \omega t}. $$

Here, $r$ is the reflection coefficient. I want to understand how can one derive (or justify) this equation?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The idea here is that you have a wave packet bouncing back and fourth in the cavity, which leaks with probability $r$ whenever it hits the right mirror. If you then whant to know what the field is one round trip later (corresponding to a time difference $\tau_{rt}$), it is simply the original field damped by $r$ and phase off-set by the frequency oscillation.

Note that this is a somewhat approximate and semi-phenomenological approach that is designed to illustrate **coupled-mode theory**, a useful tool to understand resonances in complex resonators and resonator arrays. You can think of it as a high-level alternative to solving Maxwell's equations, similar to the circuit laws in electric theory.